# View removed before it loads

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

I am trying to remove a View after getting data from webservice.

But when I removes the view using

[self.view removeFromSuperView];

the view gets removed before loading the required data. I need to load the data and then remove the view. Is there a way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using NSURLConnection then you should use the delegates methods which is

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

Here you can easily do the removing part of the view. and it will not crash unless got response.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing view in viewDidAppear after checking the result of web service using some bool variable.